# how to draw path into canvas in android?

Tags: android, canvas

hi i want to draw path into canvas but it does not do anything, it does not draw the canvas either.
my code:

```
Path path = new Path();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

for (int i = 5; i < 50; i++)
{
    path.setLastPoint(4, i - 1);
    path.lineTo(4, i);
}
path.close();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    View iview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null);
    iview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);//.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[i]);

    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mDrawable.setBounds(10, 10, 15, 15);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);

    iview.draw(canvas);
    realViewSwitcher.addView(iview);
}
```

it shows me only green color which is the default value of the `view.backroundColor`.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Canvas` is just a "tool" for drawing over a `Bitmap`. You need to associate them this way:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(someBitmap);
```

However this only lets you draw on someBitmap. If you want to draw in the view, you have to do that in `onDraw(Canvas)`, using the `Canvas` you're provided with, which is already bound with the bitmap that is the real view's drawing.

To use `onDraw()`, you have to make a custom View (that is, extend from some `View`).

Then there is `SurfaceView` but that's another thing (and I don't know much about it).